# How can I filter all my friends that are not grouped in any list, yet

Tags: facebook, friends, list

I want all my friends to be nicely grouped in lists like "Family", "Work" etc.
Is there a way to display only those friends not yet listed so that I can put them into lists as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no nice way of doing this. Fortunately, simply [loading all of your friends](http://www.facebook.com/#!/friends/?filter=afp) and scanning down this list looking for "Add to List" is a fairly quick process. (Unless you have hundreds/thousands of friends...)

Comment: Awesome! I never saw that page. Many many thanks!